# Algorithm to determine correct character ['╦', '╣', '╠', '╩', '╬'] for intersections in grid

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grid, ascii, ascii-art

I cannot even begin to wrap my head around this.

Given an array of binary values with 0 corresponding to open space and 1 being a wall:

```
11111111111111111111
10001000000000000001
10101111111010101111
10101111111010100001
10101111111010111101
10101111111010000001
10100000000010111111
11111111111111111111
```

How could you write an algorithm to change it to something like this:

```
╔═══╦══════════════╗
║   ║              ║
║ ║ ╠╦╦╦╦╦╗ ║ ║ ═══╣
║ ║ ╠╬╬╬╬╬╣ ║ ║    ║
║ ║ ╠╬╬╬╬╬╣ ║ ╚═══ ║
║ ║ ╚╩╩╩╩╩╝ ║      ║
║ ║         ║ ╔╦╦╦╦╣
╚═╩═════════╩═╩╩╩╩╩╝

╔═══╦══════════════╗
║   ║              ║
║ ║ ╠═════╗ ║ ║ ═══╣
║ ║ ║     ║ ║ ║    ║
║ ║ ║     ║ ║ ╚═══ ║
║ ║ ╚═════╝ ║      ║
║ ║         ║ ╔════╝
╚═╩═════════╩═╝
```

I would really appreciate any kind of guidance for this problem. Javascript would be preferred but anything would help!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question. Generally, users here want to see code you wrote at least as a start. In this scenario, I would start by replacing the 1s and 0s with your grid objects (regardless of rotation). Then go from there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to get some code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job.

```
function toMap(str){
    var chars = " ║═╚║║╔╠═╝═╩╗╣╦╬";
    var arr = str.split("\n");
    var v = (x,y,s)=>(y >= 0 && x >= 0 && y < arr.length && arr[y].charAt(x)==="1") << (s|0);
    return arr.map((r,y)=>r.split("").map((c,x)=>chars.charAt(v(x,y)&&(v(x,y-1)|v(x+1,y,1)|v(x,y+1,2)|v(x-1,y,3)))).join("")).join("\n")
}

toMap(`11111111111111111111
10001000000000000001
10101111111010100111
10101011111010100001
10101110111010111101
10101111111010000001
10100000000010111111
111111111111111`)
```

To understand the whole code, I recommend that you inflate the code and start debugging it and annotating it with comments.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured there was a really clever way to do this, I just wasn't sure what to search for or where to start. This will help me immensely.

Comment: For me it doesn't handle the top left corner, probably because the 'x-1', 'y-1' checks aren't resolving.  I think a Fiddle of it working would be a good prerequisite to it being accepted as an answer but it's your call.

Comment: It's working for me. I'm feeding it binary matrices from a maze generator and I haven't seen any errors yet but there is always a 1 in the top left so I get what you are saying

Comment: @christutty, i took care of negative indices, I think what you experience is the " added by the console when you log Strings (an "serialization error" one could say). try to prepend a "\n", so the first row is shown in the console in the same column as the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest answer to "How could you write an algorithm..." is "Think about it" but I agree that it can be difficult to get started.

Often the best approach is to cut the problem up so just think about one cell at a time, starting with the top left.  To decide which character to place you're going to have to test the surrounding cells to find how many connecting walls exist and then have some logic that will tell you which character to use in each situation (no connecting walls = x, one wall down = y, one wall down and one left = z, etc).

Make sense?